# Safely importing external libraries during runtime in C#

Tags: c#, file, dll, reflection, .net-assembly

I am building a program where I intend to provide an API, allowing other developers to build .dll libraries that are placed in a folder which my program can find at runtime and import them.  I find the files and load them with Assembly.load(), then find the classes using Assembly.GetExportedTypes() which implement a particular interface.

This code is functioning correctly, but frankly I have some concerns about what developers could be importing, particularly with regard to actions such as running executables from their code, trying to access or delete files on the system outside of the program's folder structure, or potentially even establishing some sort of network connection and passing data forward.

I understand that I must accept some level of risk when allowing this sort of feature, but what can I do to harden the program from malicious activity while still allowing the import of external libraries for extensibility?

Comment: Well if you re calling functions inside those DLL files, you can't have any control.

If you tell us a bot more about what you want to accomplish (what the other developers can do) we might be able to suggest a different approach.

Perhaps you can review plugins and somehow sign them.

Comment: Depending on your use case you could implement a sandbox in a different appdomain eg: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/misc/how-to-run-partially-trusted-code-in-a-sandbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/misc/how-to-run-partially-trusted-code-in-a-sandbox)

Comment: @thehennyy So in a sense the sandbox idea as outlined isn't so much creating a blacklist of what the code can't do so much as a whitelist describing what the code CAN access?

Comment: Yes a whitelist should be much safer.

Comment: @thehennyy I notice ist says to use the CreateInstanceAndUnwrap() method, but it looks like that applies to creating an instance of a type in another assembly, am I correct in saying that with this there is no other code needed to load the assembly and keep it in memory?

Comment: In general there is not much special code needed. You just need some kind of bridge to share information between the appdomains - as you already found, CreateInstanceAndUnwrap is the way to create one. Assemblies can not be unloaded except you shut down the whole appdomain they were loaded in. Maybe you can elaborate on your use case and then reopen the question.